# What do you call it when someone makes the same mistake again?

Tags: phrase-request

In Russian, there's an expression that literally translates as "to step on the same rake". What do you call it when someone makes the same mistake again? I wonder whether English has its own phrase for it

Comment: This question on EL&U is about the same Russian expression: [Is there an idiom for making the same mistake repeatedly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/303595/80039) I don't think any of the answers there are particularly good though.

Comment: I actually rather like the literal translation, which is easy to understand as a piece of figurative speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the literal translation is an expression used in English, and I don't think the other suggestions from [a similar question on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/303595/80039) capture the idea that the mistake is one someone has made before and keeps making. I can't think of a better way to express that meaning in English as concisely as "step on the same rake".

Some examples of "step on the same rake" being used in English:

> How many time are you going to **step on the same rake**? In this case it is the beaten-to-death UPC ruse. ([Source](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/25137321))

> We’ve all been there. Okay, I have. I promised myself not to **step on the same rake** twice but boy, those online deals just got me big time. ([Source](https://www.boredpanda.com/online-shopping-fails-scams/))

> Why are we still **stepping on the same rake** over and over again? Why don’t we learn from others’ mistakes? ([Source](https://www.isaca.org/resources/news-and-trends/isaca-now-blog/2020/the-fine-art-of-stepping-on-the-same-rake))

Comment: Is it really idiomatic? I can't say the sources are particularly authoritative

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I’ve used it before I knew it was an expression in Russian. I think this is one of those rare cases where an expression translates well literally. I wonder about the origins of it. With English there’s a good chance it was plagiarized from another language (:

Answer (score 0):

While it's not used exclusively for mistakes, you could, in many contexts, say they are a "glutton for punishment".

"You keep taking Jamie back even though you know she's just going to break your heart again, you must be a glutton for punishment."

"You mouthed off to another huge dude at a bar? You're such a glutton for punishment."